# The debugging task cannot be configured automatically in launch.json

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

VSCode does not automatically generate a proper launch.json file for my c++ code. It does not add a preLaunchTask. Here is an animated gif showing my steps:
[This is my mistake all over again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKhZk.gif)
[Here is my launch provided Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3vP6.png)

Any ideas how to fix VSCode so that I don't have to manually configure my launch.json every time?

Comment: Did you actually try to edit your `launch.json` to add this? Your video goes so fast. Or is your complaint that VSCode generates an unexpected launch.json

Comment: i can edit the launch.json manual,but i want my tasks automatic configuration.